# Mac not letting me install 'Packages" by Stephan Sudre

Tags: install, dmg, package-management, pkg

I am trying to install "Packages", to create an installation package for an App I am developing. After I mount the disk image file, I am trying to start the installation process by launching the .pkg file. However, this only opens the encoding.

[image]

[image]

How do I install the app from here?

I have tried changing the application that this opens with, but any app opens the encoding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select 'Choose Application', then go to `/System/Library/CoreServices`, and choose `Installer.app`.

Comment: Is there a way to set that as default? When I go into Get Info, it doesn't show up there.